# prototype window pop up document.observe function error. TypeError: $$(...)[0] is undefined

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, prototype-js, popup

I keep getting this error and my lack of JS knowledge is not helping.

I ripped this code from another post.

```
function showPopup(sUrl, id) {
    oPopup = new Window({
        id: id,
        className: 'magento',
        url: sUrl,
        width: awidth,
        height: aheight,
        minimizable: false,
        maximizable: false,
        showEffectOptions: {
            duration: 0.4
        },
        hideEffectOptions: {
            duration: 0.4
        },
        destroyOnClose: true
    });
    oPopup.setZIndex(100);
    oPopup.showCenter(true);
}

document.observe("dom:loaded", function () {
    $$('button selector')[0].observe('click', function (oEvent) {
        showPopup($(this).readAttribute('href'));
        Event.stop(oEvent);
    });
});
```

I tried assigning the id as well. where id: 'theid'

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$('theid')[0].observe('click', function(oEvent) {
        showPopup($(this).readAttribute('href'));
        Event.stop(oEvent);
    });
});
```

The pop up works I'm using this function for compare and the newsletter but I can't get rid of the error. I modified the function a bit but this is the original code. More specifically I'm using `prototype/window.js` with the magento css theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the popup code, this worked for my needs.

```
function addNewPop(id,title,w,h){
win = new Window({
    title: title,
    className:"magento",
    destroyOnClose: true, 
    recenterAuto:false, 
    width:w,
    height:h,
    id: title,
    minimizable: false,
    maximizable: false,
    showEffectOptions: {
        duration: 0.4
    },
    hideEffectOptions:{
        duration: 0.4,
    }
});
win.setZIndex(100);
win.showCenter(true);
win.setContent(id, false, false);
//hide div on close
$(title + '_close').observe('click', function(event) {
    $(id).setStyle({display: 'none'});
});
```

}